# the drawer covers the page

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

my drawer is covering the page i want it to be flex to the left without covering any content. this is my first time  using material-ui so if anyone can explain i would appreciate that

`````
const drawerWidth = 240;

const SideBar = (props) => {
  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: { display: "flex" },
  }));
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <Drawer
        sx={{
          width: drawerWidth,
          flexShrink: 0,
          "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
            width: drawerWidth,
            boxSizing: "border-box",
          },
        }}
        variant="permanent"
        anchor="left"
      >
        <Toolbar />

        <List>
          <Divider />
          {props.jobs.map((job, i) => (
            <ListItem
              alignItems="flex-start"
              key={i}
              onClick={() => {
                props.onClick(job);
              }}
            >
              <ListItemText primary={job.title} secondary={job.career_level} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Drawer>
    </div>````
`````

Comment: Did you copy [this](https://mui.com/components/drawers/#permanent-drawer) section and it doesn't work out for you? I failed to understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably looking for is the `variant='persistent'` drawer

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled, useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Drawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import MuiAppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronRight';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Mail';

const drawerWidth = 240;

const Main = styled('main', { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open' })(
  ({ theme, open }) => ({
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    marginLeft: `-${drawerWidth}px`,
    ...(open && {
      transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
      }),
      marginLeft: 0,
    }),
  }),
);

const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open',
})(({ theme, open }) => ({
  transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  ...(open && {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    marginLeft: `${drawerWidth}px`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  }),
}));

const DrawerHeader = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
  // necessary for content to be below app bar
  ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
}));

export default function PersistentDrawerLeft() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="fixed" open={open}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            sx={{ mr: 2, ...(open && { display: 'none' }) }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap component="div">
            Persistent drawer
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        sx={{
          width: drawerWidth,
          flexShrink: 0,
          '& .MuiDrawer-paper': {
            width: drawerWidth,
            boxSizing: 'border-box',
          },
        }}
        variant="persistent"
        anchor="left"
        open={open}
      >
        <DrawerHeader>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            {theme.direction === 'ltr' ? <ChevronLeftIcon /> : <ChevronRightIcon />}
          </IconButton>
        </DrawerHeader>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem button key={text}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {['All mail', 'Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem button key={text}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Drawer>
      <Main open={open}>
        <DrawerHeader />
        <Typography paragraph>
          Content
        </Typography>
        <Typography paragraph>
          More content
        </Typography>
      </Main>
    </Box>
  );
}
```